# UIButton and selectors iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector

I have a button constructor class and in that class i have this method to design my buttons

```
- (void)setupWithPosition:(CGPoint)point withImage:(UIImage *)image withImageFloat:(NSString *)imageFloat withTitle:(NSString *)title withLineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth respondsToSelector:(NSString*)selector
{
    // create button
    ButtonWithImage* button = [[ButtonWithImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];

    //[button setTitle:[title uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setupViewWithText:title andImage:image andImageFloat:imageFloat];


    [button addTarget:self
               action:NSSelectorFromString(selector)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
    CGFloat lineX = 0.0f;


    // setup image
    if ([[imageFloat lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"right"]) {
        lineX = buttonFrame.origin.x + buttonFrame.size.width;
    } else {
        lineX = 0.0f;
        buttonFrame.origin.x = lineWidth;
        button.frame = buttonFrame;
    }

    self.line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lineX, buttonFrame.size.height/2, lineWidth, LINE_HEIGHT)];
    self.line.backgroundColor = [UIColor lineNormalColor];


    [self addSubview:self.line];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

and i'm calling that using:

```
homepageButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CategoryButtonView* za = [[CategoryButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 300, 46)];
    [za setupWithPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100) withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zas.png"] withImageFloat:@"right" withTitle:@"za" withLineWidth:80.0f respondsToSelector:@"buttonClicked"];
```

the buttons are placed correctly but when i click on them i get that error

```
CategoryButtonView buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1a46a0
2012-11-02 17:53:43.844 Man[3432:14c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CategoryButtonView buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1a46a0'
```

i guess its a SEL problem how can i solve that?

Answer (score 3):

You have this line:

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:NSSelectorFromString(selector)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Do you really want 'self' here? This means that whatever selector you pass in must be a method in the `CategoryButtonView` class, not whatever class is used to create the `CategoryButtonView`.

Most likely you want to add a `target` parameter along with the `selector` parameter.

Comment: ok if i add a target parameter with self as parameter form my other view again it crashes and i get that error:   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController buttonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89764d0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: ButtonClicked takes a UIButton as a parameter which is the sender

Answer (score 0):

had to add that to make it work

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",selector];

    [button addTarget:sender
               action:NSSelectorFromString(temp)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Why are you adding the colon there? That should be part of the selector string you pass in as a parameter. Now your code will break if you want to use a select that doesn't actually take a parameter.